# How to find key points in 2 images automatically for homography?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

At first, thanks to dear Christoph Rackwitz that guided me to write some parts of this code by python and opencv.

I have a question! This is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__' :

     # Read source image.
     im_dst = cv2.imread('c:/36.jpg')
     # Four corners of the book in source image
     pts_dst = np.array([[314, 107], [693, 107], [903, 493],[311, 491]])

     # Read destination image.
     im_src = cv2.imread('c:/pitch.jpg')
     # Four corners of the book in destination image.
     pts_src = np.array([[487, 81],[575, 81],[575, 297],[487, 297]])

     # Calculate Homography
     h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)

     # Warp source image to destination based on homography
     im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]), borderValue=[255,255,255])
     mask = im_out[:,:,0] < 100

     im_out_overlapped = im_dst.copy()
     im_out_overlapped[mask] = [0,0,255]
     # Display images
     cv2.imshow("Source Image", im_src)
     cv2.imshow("Destination Image", im_dst)
     cv2.imshow("Warped Source Image", im_out)
     cv2.imshow("Warped", im_out_overlapped)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
```

with this code I can import these 2 images :

[image: pitch.jpg]

[image: 36.jpg]

and the result is this : (after warpPerspective)

[image: result]

Now I have a new problem, as you see in code: for doing homography between my 2 images, I should import 4 points coordinates (4 corners of right penalty area) for each image, it means we need to find 8 points coordinates.

Is there a way that my app finds these coordinates points AUTOMATICALLY in both images? And don't I need to write coordinates of points myself?

Comment: This task is uneasy. As all soccer fields are identical, you can process the top image "by hand", once for all. I mean Identify the key points and/or edges. Then in the bottom image, you can try Hough lines and match the detected lines or corners to corresponding edges or vertices in the top image. You can rate a tentative correspondence by evaluating the homography and checking the matching of the remaining, unused edges. Alternatively, a best fit algorithm can give you a matching score. You will try several correspondences, and keep the one that fits best.

Comment: thanks. but  , define key points in  (pitch.jpg ) (top view) is easy  and once for all time because it is static , but othere image is impossible because i should change this  image many times that each image have different angle and position of field

Comment: and i know the best way is find intersection of lines ,  and you wrote that i can use homography for lines ! how homography can match only points , not lines

Comment: An homography transforms points into points and lines into lines. You can determine an homography from equations of lines.